# AppEngine: creating my own UserService?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session, authentication

I have been learning Google AppEngine for a couple of weeks... now I am integrating it with Gwt for my web application.

The "guestbook" GAE tutorial is very interesting, if you know what I'm talking about.

I loved the so easy integration with Google Accounts, it's very useful but...

my customer is not interested in it, he wants standard, classic authentication system.

So I'll have my own "User" entity in the datastore, and so on. I can do that.

What I can't do is creating my own UserService, for checking *wherever* in my App wheter the user is logged in or not.

I mean I'm not so good at manage Sessions, Cookies, or whatever is needed to achieve my goal. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Have you looked at the federated auth option? If they don't want Google logins, what's wrong with OpenID?

Comment: @Nick Honestly, I think it's a valid request.  While there are plenty of people that love having a single sign-on, I've encountered at least an equal number of users (esp. those outside the Google eco-system) that find it confusing and/or annoying.  The lack of a single sign-out solution is particularly troublesome.

Comment: @Kevin I don't disagree - but the OP didn't mention having considered OpenID, so I thought it was worth mentioning. There are reasons someone might want to avoid the regular Users API but still be happy with OAuth.

Comment: @Nick I was aware of OpenId, sorry for not mentioning it. I confirm what Kevin said: in this case I do need a "traditional" auth system, but.... if I want to learn more about that solution, can you address me in the right place, please? THank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your only problem is to know if the user is logged in, the solution is straightforward.

In the authentication code, once the user is authenticated:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("loggedIn", Boolean.TRUE);
```

Anywhere in the code:

```
boolean loggedIn = request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedIn") != null;
```

If you have a "Logout" action :

```
request.getSession().removeAttribute("loggedIn");
```

The attributes in the session are stored at server-side. They're not sent as cookies to the client, so there's no security risk.

Comment: In my use case, in any Gwt RemoteServiceServlet extension, I will check the request/session and I did it! :) Anyway, you mention "your only problem" like if there's something more to know to have a good authentication system. What did you mean?

Comment: I mean that usually, the difficult part is not how to check the user is authenticated, but rather how to authenticate him securely (salting and hashing passwords, etc.), how to make sure a whole set of URLs is only accessible to authenticated users without forcing an explicit check in all the protected resources (using a filter is a good solution here), and how to redirect the user to the login page, authenticate him, and then redirect him to the page he wanted to go to.